# Why am I getting this JSON Parse error when fetching data from laravel 5.5 via async-await?

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await, fetch, laravel-5.5

I am using a combination of Laravel and javascript to return data from the database. Unfortunately I am getting the following error

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

However I am using the toJson() function in laravel so I have no idea why it is saying it is not properly parsed

Action From Controller

```
public function getSourceListForSpecificSystem(int $system_id){
    $systems = $this->sourceObject->select('id','name')->where('systems_id',$system_id)->whereNull('deleted')->get()->toJson();
    return $systems;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const getSources = async function(systemId){
    try{
        const response = await fetch('/sources/get_systems_sources/'+systemId);
        const json = await response.json();
        await console.log(json);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
    //console.log(json);
};

getSources(systemId);
```

now if I call the url directly from the browser I get what appears to be correct data

```
([{"id":1,"name":"Players Handbook"}])
```

I am sure I am just doing something stupid, but I am not sure what that is.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Your third `await` there doesn't do anything - `console.log` is synchronous. (on the Javascript side, at least)

Comment: Have you looked at the plain text response from `.text()`, or in the network tab?

Comment: chances are the server is sending invalid JSON .. and if it's exactly what you say it is `([{"id":1,"name":"Players Handbook"}])` including the `()` then, yes, it's invalid

Comment: it returns [{"id":1,"name":"Players Handbook"}] No parenthesis